# MySQL specific sorting of the result based on multiply 'LIKE' and better matching of the founded results

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm trying to build search engine and wondering is there a way to sort the results based on more precise matching?

I have a simple table `library` with the user names stored there:

| userName |
| --- |
| john hampton |
| smith horne |
| john smith junior |
| kevin spencer |
| john white smith |
| luke junior |
| alan smith junior |

based on search field inputs. For example if I want to search for **`john smith junior`** I would like not only to check for the full name matching,  also  want to check for the matching part of the name. so expected result should be:

| userName |
| --- |
| john smith junior |
| john white smith |
| alan smith junior |
| john hampton |
| smith horne |
| luke junior |

First line need to be top rated as we have three matches, second and third line have two matches and rest there is just one match, but ordered by the input field submission.

I started to build following query:

```
SELECT `userName`
FROM `library`
WHERE `userName` like '%john%smith%junior'
  OR `userName` like '%john%smith%'
  OR `userName` like '%john%junior%'
  OR `userName` like '%smith%junior%'
  OR `userName` like '%john%'
  OR `userName` like '%smith%'
  OR `userName` like '%junior%'
ORDER BY ???
```

but I blocked how to sort of the results, so my question is - is it possible to add some special clauses in ORDER BY to get results sorted as required (priority based on where clause adding order)?

1. First all results  where '%john%smith%junior' sorted ASC
2. Second all results where `userName` like '%john%smith%' sorted ASC
3. etc.
4. Last is all results where `userName` like '%junior%' sorted ASC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
...
ORDER BY (`userName` like '%john%smith%junior') * @weight1 +
         (`userName` like '%john%smith%')       * @weight2 +
         (`userName` like '%john%junior%')      * @weight3 +
         (`userName` like '%smith%junior%')     * @weight4 +
         (`userName` like '%john%')             * @weight5 +
         (`userName` like '%smith%')            * @weight6 +
         (`userName` like '%junior%')           * @weight7
```

Take into account that real weight of the condition is a sum of weights for it and all its subconditions.

For example, a row which matches condition `like '%john%smith%'` also matches `like '%john%'` and `like '%smith%'`, i.e. actual weight of this pattern is `@weight2 + @weight5 + @weight6`.

Comment: Great! Many thanks @Akina , this is exactly what I was looking for! Cheers!